# Javascript : if statement is not working on while/for loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop, conditional-statements

*The code below is working until a condition is added on loop.*

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- This code is working--> 
<script>
var n=parseInt(prompt("Enter a number:"));
while(n>=1){
    document.write(n+' /  2<br>');
    n=n/2;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

*But the same code does not run when I add a condition:*

```
<html>
<body>
    <!-- This code is not working -->
<script>
var n=parseInt(prompt("Enter a number:"));
while(n>=1){
    if(n%2!=0){
        n=3*n+1; 
        }
    document.write(n+' /  2<br>');
    n=n/2;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you stepped through it with a debugger?

Comment: debugger get  hang/crash when I try to run.(same thing happened on multiple devices)

Comment: Your code runs. It just never stops.

Comment: Exactly, can you tell me why this happened?

Comment: The problem is with ```3*n+1``` by removing that it works fine. need to check where the error is

Comment: I use ```n=n+1``` instead of ```n=3*n+1``` but it still crashing.

Comment: I found a way to stop a loop check if its work for you @AHN change the while condition from ```n>=1``` to ```n>1```. Because the condition never breaks and the loop runs for infinite time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the answer**

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var n=parseInt(prompt("Enter a number:"));
while(n>=1){
    if(n%2!=0){
        n=n+1; 
        }
    console.log(n);
    n=n/2;
    if(n==1){break;}//this will stop Infinity loop 
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because the while loop will never stop running as n will always be greater than 1.

Why? Because you are multiplying it by 3 and then dividing by 2 which actually increasing the given n.

For example if `n = 5` in first case,

it will be `n = 3*n+1 = 16`
Then `n = n/2 = 8`

As you can see the first n = 5 becomes n = 8. Therefore it will never break the while loop as n will never decrease to 0. Even though it seems that for n = 8, the next iteration will be

n = 4 // as 8%2 == 0
n = 2 // again 4%2 == 0
n = 1// as 2%2 == 0

Now as 1%2!==0 now the if statement will be executed,

So,
n = 4 as n = 3n+1 => 3*1 + 1 => 4;

Now it will go into the same path again.
n = 4
n =2
n =1
n=4
n=2
n=1

Therefore it will never get out of the while loop and run infinitely.

Update:

To remove the infinite loop you need to change the condition of while loop to while(n>1). And you need to write n = Math.round(n/2) instead of n = n/2 as n/2 might result in floating number.

Comment: Your example and explanation are flawed. The number 6 will not have the polynomial applied as it is an even number. Edit your answer to indicate **odd numbers** will always increase and you're on the right track.

Comment: Same things happened if I use   ```n=n+1 ``` instead of   ```n=3*n+1```

Comment: Just add a console.log(n) in your console and check the value of n. You will understand where the problem is.

Comment: @sabbir.alam it din't get stop when the value of n come to 2

Comment: It shouldn't be supposed to stop as I have described above it will be an infinite loop. To remove the infinite loop you need to change the condition of while loop to while(n>1). And you need to write n = Math.round(n/2)  instead of n = n/2 as n/2 might result in floating number.